# Kubuntu won't install/boot HP Pavilion Laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, uefi

I am trying to install kubuntu so that I can dual boot with that and Windows. Im using Kubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I've already flashed the usb and partitioned space on the hard drive. I had gotten to the installation menu and after selecting which installation I wanted, (normal installation) I got an error that ubi-partman had crashed with exit code 141. I tried retrying but that didnt work so I had to reboot. The problem kept happening so I booted into windows. I wiped the usb and re-flashed the iso onto it. This time, the computer brought me to a black screen with an error message. I managed to take a picture before the computer shut off. It said:

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to Load Image \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi: Not Found
Failed to Start MokManager: Not Found
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed : Not Found
```

I don't know what any of this means and I cant seem to fix it. I've tried enabling Legacy Support in the BIOS settings as well as turning off Secure Boot. I've also tried resetting my BIOS settings to the default values and that didn't help. Does anyone know what Im doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu community. I'm sorry that you are facing issues even before installing OS. I'm not sure what's happening there. But if I were you, first, I will cross verify the checksum of ISO image. If that's matching, since you already facing issue installing alongside Windows, I would recommend you to use VirtualBox and test whether the issue happening there. It will also save you most of the time testing by reinstalling, since you don't have to boot your system every time. If you don't find any issues in VBox, it is likely possible that, you have hardware issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could boot into the live environment after redownloading the iso and reflashing it to the usb, then turning on legacy support

Answer (score 0):

This issue's been fixed in a few instances by modifying the boot disk.  In \EFI\BOOT\ make a duplicate of grubx64.efi and rename it mmx64.efi then try and run the install. Altering the boot disk can be a bit fiddly but there's been a fair bit of success with this fix on dual boot systems.  Let me know if that solves it for you, if not creating a UEFI-only boot media has also resolved this in a lot of cases.

Comment: I saw this solution before but I'm not sure how to edit it. I've extracted it with 7zip but after i changed it I dont know how to recompile it. If theres any free software that would be great but I dont really want to pay for anything like poweriso